# jquery, java script как улучшить производительность

Tags: javascript, jquery, производительность

Делаю приложение типа `TODO list (список задач)`, пишу на `PHP, JS  и JQuery`, знаю все это так себе, хочу сделать приложение чтобы работало полностью без перезагрузки и соответственно много ajax запросов. Но вот  беда, вроде особо ничего не сделал, а как залил на хостинг при добавлении задачи или выборе в `datapickere`  образуется задержка в `0,5-1 секунду` примерно, это очень не комфортно, особенно на телефоне.

Подскажите как поступить в таком случае, мне кажется это слишком долго учитывая что в приложении почти нет функций.

Вот [ссылка](http://formyday.ru/) если будет понятней

[image: ][1]]

пока еще все криво, я жe чайник = )))

Comment: [сайт](http://formyday.ru)

Comment: при первом запросе даты задержка около секунды, последующая  средняя задержка 85ms при выборе дат. Почему при выборе даты отправляется 2 запроса?

Comment: Не нужно приводить проблему "у меня где-то на сайте". Разбираться вряд ли кто будет, да и можно усмотреть нагон трафика, что плохо. Приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример тут, в сниппете.

Comment: два запроса потому что видимо один это перезагрузка датапикера, я его убрал но вроде особо ничего не поменялось

Comment: other: на сайте там особо ничего нет, по этому не сложно найти, я не особо в этом разбираюсь и по этому не смог письменно эту проблему описать

Comment: теперь на при добавлении задачи происходит три запроса 1) добавляет задачу , 2-й выберает задачи из бд и выводит их, 3-й перезагрузка датапикера (чтобы дата закрашивалась сразу без перезагрузки окна. на локалхосте добавление задачи занимает 60ms 10ms и 7ms(это три запроса) в среднем а на хостинге уже 300ms, 150ms, 70ms,